# How to express an increase in sth during some years?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice

I want to express an increase in annual sales of my company from 2013 to 2018. I have written the following sentence. I don't know why, but I feel that it's somehow strange, isn't it? If so, any suggestion.

I am proud to announce that the annual sales **volume** of my company in the 2018 financial year **is**(or has become) seven times(or sevenfold) **as high as**(or higher than) **that** in 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may rephrase as follows:

> I am proud to announce that the sales volume of my company in  financial year 2018 is seven times as much  as that in 2013.

Comment: A high sales volume is correct, so a comparative form works  - higher, as high as. I'd prefer higher than in the OP's original. It's also 2019, so, 2018 "was"

Comment: A company is likely to simplify the statement to something like: **sales in 2018 showed a 700% improvement on 2013** or  **....were seven times greater than in 2013**.